# Saving player statistics (different for each game) to database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise

I probably could not find anything about this because I don't know how to describe it.

I have the following setup:

- A user account can have a profile with basic information (name, age), optional and there can also be a profile without associated account.
- A profile can be linked to several gameprofiles (one for each game)
- A gameprofile has an ingame name and should be where I can find a player's statistics.

Now, for different games, there are different statistics. Do I really need to create another model for each game with the associated attributes or is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Okomikeruko makes a good point about different game stats described by different attributes. You should be warned though that `hash in string` approach will complicate querying and indexing this table.

Alternative is to have two tables for keeping game stats, one being the `header` table, carrying attributes such as game session dates, duration, etc. and the `detail` table, keeping the game-specific attributes:

```
# pseudocode:

GameProfile
  has_many :game_profile_details
end

GameProfileDetail
  belongs_to :game_profile

  stat_name: string
  stat_value: string
end
```

Comment: I think I prefer your implementation because it is more "Rails-like". I should have specified that I meant games as in video games, or synonymous with sports. So I will add GameStats to each Game and then reference the GameStat from the GameProfileDetail - but this definitely pointed me in the right direction, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a generic model that holds the statistics for a given game.

Since each game would have some stats that are identical (name?, high score?) you could set those up easily.

The tricky part would be how to handle different game stats. One game might have a "best time" while another "turns used".

To handle this, you could save other data as a hash in a string.

So it would save `meta_data: "{'best_time' => '0:04:23.6', 'other' => 'thing'}"` in one game but you wouldn't need to leave an empty `best_time` field for games that don't use one.

Then when you load the data, based on the game, you could code

```
<%= @gamedata.meta_data.best_time %>
# returns "0:04:23.6"
```

Comment: Good solution, but I will use a modified version of Nic Nilov's. Thanks, though!

Comment: Agreed. I did something similar to @Nic_Nilov's solution in another project. I was basing my recommendation on my recent experience using Stripe's API.